# How to let already copied files share fragments (reflink)?

Tags: backup, file-copy, xfs, deduplication

I copy a file to a different XFS volume on daily basis as follows:

```
# on monday
cp --sparse=always /mnt/disk1/huge.file /mnt/disk2/monday/huge.file
# on tuesday
cp --sparse=always /mnt/disk1/huge.file /mnt/disk2/tuesday/huge.file
```

Now it occupies the full size of both files on disk2.

On the same partition I would usually use `--reflink=auto`, so the copied file shares fragments and occupies only the changed blocks. But as this does not work if the destination is on a different volume, I need a solution to reflink two already existing copies.

Sadly `cp` does not copy only changed blocks like `rsync` (no reflink support) does, else I would do:

```
# on monday
cp --sparse=always /mnt/disk1/huge.file /mnt/disk2/huge.file
cp --reflink=always /mnt/disk2/huge.file /mnt/disk2/monday/huge.file
# on tuesday
cp --sparse=always /mnt/disk1/huge.file /mnt/disk2/huge.file
cp --reflink=always /mnt/disk2/huge.file /mnt/disk2/tuesday/huge.file
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about xfs but btrfs has a commands for deduplication that do this.
See https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Deduplication

You could run a deduplication step independently of the copy.

To do what you are asking directly you can reverse your process.

Something like:

1. create a ref-link from yesterdays copy to create a baseline

   cp --reflink=always /mnt/disk2/monday/huge.file /mnt/disk2/tuesday/huge.file
2. read the source file from the other location and write updates into it directly
   Something like:

   rsync --inplace --no-whole-file /mnt/disk1/huge.file /mnt/disk2/tuesday/huge.file

Hopefully only the unchanged blocks will be shared between Monday and Tuesday's backups as required.

caveat: I have not tried this and don't know it will actually do what you want.

See https://superuser.com/questions/576035/does-rsync-inplace-write-to-the-entire-file-or-just-to-the-parts-that-need-to

This is possibly irrelevant but there is also some talk of adding reflink support directly to rsync.
See:

- https://github.com/WayneD/rsync/issues/153
- https://www.reddit.com/r/btrfs/comments/ijby0b/does_rsync_support_reflinks_for_btrfs/

I am not that clear on the issue there.